# Angular 2 : Apply directive on dynamic html

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive

I'm creating a directive to edit a single field. The idea is simple, I apply a directive to the element I want to edit, something like this :

```
<div edit-field>
    blabla
</div>
```

My directive will add a button next to the field, when the user click on it, it transform the field into an input.

To do that, I need to change the HTML. The problem is that my buttons and inputs need to have a directive applied to it.

Here is some code of what I did so far :

```
private editButton: string =
    `
        <button md-button>
            Edit
        </button>
    `;

private element: HTMLElement;

constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.element = el.nativeElement;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.element.innerHTML = this.element.innerHTML + this.editButton;
}
```

As you can see, the button has a `md-button` directive. When I check the result, the directive is not applied.

I saw some post about dynamic component loader but I can't figure out how to apply this in my case.

Any tips/helps is welcome :)

Comment: There is no way in angular to dynamically apply a directive, you could only create components dynamically.

Comment: @Robouste Have you added the import `import {MdButtonModule} from '@angular/material';` to your  app.module? [https://material.angular.io/components/button/api][1]

Comment: This is the `AngularJS` approach. You can't do that anymore in Angular. Read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: oh, that's very sad :(
@todo Yes, I've imported everything :)